# Reading text files one word at a time until end of file and display on textblock

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way I can read a text file, one word at a time, until the end of the file.
This is my code at the moment but it is only reading one word from the file and no more.
How can I process the entire file?

```
 var ResourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("test.txt",UriKind.Relative));
            using (Stream myFileStream = ResourceStream.Stream)
            {
                string s = "";
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);
                s = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                s = s.Trim();
                //tlbwords.Text = s;
                char[] delimiters = { '\n', '\r' };
                string[] words = s.Split(delimiters);
                tlbwords.Text = words[0];
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);` and then separate the words.

Comment: Actually if you are using a text block that allows for multiple lines I believe you can also just say `tlbwords.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);`

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ to get all words:

```
var words = File
   .ReadAllLines(fileName)
   .SelectMany(line -> line.Split(' '))
   .Where(word => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
   .ToArray();
```

**Edit** with Julián Urbano suggestion:

```
var words = File
   .ReadAllLines(fileName)
   .SelectMany(line -> line.Split(' ',  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 if you comment about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx

Comment: Thanks @JuliánUrbano, I never knew about overload to Split.

Comment: Reading up on Split in MSDN.  We can also pass null as the 1st argument to Split and it will use any Unicode whitespace character.

Comment: or just don't pass any parameter at all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

and set Multiline to true